# Running multiple test with connectedCheck using Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am using [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/). I have multiple tests written, all in different classes but the same project. When I run I remove all but one class and try running, it runs fine. However, when I have them all in my project and try running the second one always fails.
All of my test are pretty basic right now. They just have `setUp()` and one `testMethod()`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**NOTE:** I run via terminal with command `gradle appName:cC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. I need to add the [Spoon Gradle Plugin](http://square.github.io/spoon/)

Answer (score 0):

That's one option, but you don't have to, you can still use gradle command `connectedCheck`
Find out how to run the tests (including running tests for a specific module and on multiple devices) here at this Google example:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint

Comment: If you see in my question, `connectedCheck` is something I was already doing. `cC` is the same thing.

Comment: I missed that, if your issue has been resolved then great. if it hasn't been resolved: in AndroidStudio, when you click on the Gradle tasks tab what do u see under the heading Verification? what tasks starting with connectedXxxxxx do you see?